# 'Close group' Vs 'Closed group'

Tags: past-participles

On Facebook, you can create a group. You can further ['classify' the group](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465) wherein there's an option - 'closed'. When you create a group, the description for that group is shown as 'Closed group'.

Now there's a catch. If someone sees this group and reads 'Closed group', it *may mean* that the group is 'closed' and no more requests for joining the group is allowed. So, here, 'closed' is opposite to 'open'.

While writing a post on social media, I was stuck due to this ambiguity.

> *You can either join a closed group or can create one.*

For a newbie, there's an obvious question - how can one join the group which is already closed! *Blame* past participle for this!

I think I can *certainly* use 'close' instead of 'closed' to avoid ambiguity.

> *You can either join a close group or ....*

What say?

Comment: A "close group" would mean "a group whose members are close", that is, whose members have close relationships (they are devoted friends or colleagues etc.), IMHO.

Comment: But then what if it has to take a limited number of members and once it's filled, it becomes 'closed group'? @CopperKettle

Comment: Probably "closed group" is ambiguous *per se*.

Comment: That's why the question is! @CopperKettle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "closed" in closed group does not mean "intimate".

It means "not public". It's opposite to the "open" in "open forum", a forum where everybody can join.

<sub>[From dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/closed)</sub>

> **closed**
>
> 3. Not public; restricted; exclusive
>
> A closed meeting; a closed bid at a private auction

So being a closed group does not pertain to the relationship of the members within that group. It means that the group is not easily accessible to people outside the group.

Comment: Ah, this is what I wanted. I missed this definition somehow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

In Facebook, a "closed group" is a group that is closed to members who are not specifically allowed in by a group administrator. See [this explanation from the Facebook help pages.](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465/?ref=u2u) The term is a bit open to confusion, but the word "closed" can mean closed to some things and open to others.  For example, bars are closed to people under a certain age, but that doesn't mean that they are closed to everyone.

A "close group" would mean a group of people that were good friends or something like that, and that isn't the meaning that Facebook is trying to convey.

Comment: I think when we talk about intimacy, 'close' should be used with a plural noun. Like 'close friends', 'close groups'. Here, if you simply ***leave*** like this -'close group', it again adds some ambiguity to my eyes.

Comment: Also, do you mean that 'close' means open to specific? What's that use of the word?

Comment: @MaulikV I'm not sure why you'd think *close* has to be used with a plural noun. For example, *a close friend of mine* is a common phrase.

Comment: I know that. That's the reason I said *"...if you **leave** like that..."*. Here, you have *an entire sentence* for that! @DamkerngT. Said that, simple 'close friend' as it is won't work; 'close friends' would...

Comment: A close group is a group of people that are close to one another in some way.  This is a different word from the verb close, and pronounced differently.  It has no relationship with the word open used as an adjective; the antonym for open is closed.

Comment: @BobRodes I don't agree with the bar example. If I see a "closed bar" sign, I see "come back another time, we are currently closed" instead of "this bar is only for X type of people".

Comment: @helix You might actually see a sign on a bar that says "Closed to minors."  This would have the meaning I describe.  A sign that just said "Closed" would have the meaning you describe.

Answer (score 1):

A close group describes the relationship within the group.  A closed group describes the relationship with the outside world.  Thus, a close group describes a group that is tightly knit and works together (Maulik V uses the word "intimacy" which is a good word for it).  Meanwhile, a closed group describes a group that draws a line between itself and the world around it.

In general, you will find that closed groups tend to be close, because its hard for such a group to survive without being close, leading to confusion between the words.